# How do I access data of all of the users of an app through the SDK (Buildfire)

Tags: javascript

I want to access all of the users for an application through a plugin that I am building.  I saw in the sdk that there is a class called userdata that has methods for CRUD operations and thought that maybe that would allow me to see the list of users for an application.

When I tried to use the userData.search method like so:

buildfire.userData.search ({}, undefined, callback)

It returns an empty array to me instead of what I thought would be the entire list of users.  Is userData just another data store for information I want to manually associate with users, or does it tap into user account information saved by the application is a whole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserData` is a data repository that is segmented by user. Meaning, if the plugin needed to save data that only pertains to the logged in user and not shared with other users like preferences, task list, ... etc. https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/User-Data:-Save-user-data-from-the-widget

`UserData` is not a list of all users in the system. BuildFire does not allow you to access all users in the system (at least currently) for security reasons.